# In Microsoft Outlook, Is it possible to create a rule to set a specific colour to a meeting invite where I'm in CC?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

I would like to set  specific colour to all meeting invites in Outlook where I'm in cc. Is it possible ?

Comment: By 'cc', do you mean 'Optional' as I didn't see a 'cc' field in a meeting invite? Besides, do you want to set a specific colour on the meeting invites message in your Inbox or on the calendar entry on your Calendar?

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer, indeed  it is to colour the invite in the calendar for invitation where I am optional

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional formatting and in the "Advanced" tab set the following rules:

```
Organizer is not empty
Cc contains Gillieaux, Luc
Cc contains luc.gillieaux@company.com
To doesn't contain Gillieaux, Luc
To doesn't contain luc.gillieaux@company.com
```

In some organisations (and combinations of Outlook and Exchange) I've found I've needed to add two further rules to cover all eventualities:

```
To doesn't contain Luc Gillieaux
Cc contains Luc Gillieaux
```